# How to call a specific UIButton by tag other than the sender?

Tags: swift, function, uibutton, tags, sender

In a simple memory game I have a struct that defines the two cards that are tapped and returns in mutating functions the integers firstFlippedCard and secondFlippedCard.

If these do not match by another property, I want both cards to 'flip back'. I made a transition function for this - however, I can only make the last tapped button to switch back using the following logic:

```
    @IBAction func cardsPress(_ sender: UIButton) {

        flip(sender: sender)

        if cardBrain.checkFirstCard(card: sender.tag - 1) == true {
            //stay flipped
        } else if cardBrain.checkForMatch(card: sender.tag - 1).match == true {
            //stay flipped
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1), execute:  {
                self.backFlip(sender: sender)
            })
        }


    }
```

Note that multiple UIButtons are linked to cardsPress. How can I make them both flip back instead of only the sender?

Comment: How about the outlet collection of these buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a property to keep track of the `previousButton` pressed.  Then use this property to flip both the current `sender` and the `previousButton`.  Finally, set `previousButton` back to `nil` after flipping it or deciding to keep it flipped.

```
var previousButton: UIButton?
var waitForFlip = false

@IBAction func cardsPress(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // ignore button input while waiting for cards to unflip
    guard !waitForFlip else { return }

    flip(sender: sender)

    if cardBrain.checkFirstCard(card: sender.tag - 1) {
        //stay flipped
        previousButton = sender
    } else if cardBrain.checkForMatch(card: sender.tag - 1).match  {
        //stay flipped
        previousButton = nil
    } else {
        waitForFlip = true
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1), execute:  {
            self.backFlip(sender: sender)
            if let button = previousButton {
                self.backFlip(sender: button)
                self.previousButton = nil
            }
            self.waitForFlip = false
        })
    }

}
```

**Notes:**

- There is a possibility that the player could start flipping another card before the previous ones flip back.  I introduced a `waitForFlip` property to ignore button inputs while we are waiting for the mismatched cards to flip back to avoid an issue where `previousButton` gets set and then overwritten to `nil` by the previous unflip.
- There is no need to check if a `Bool` value is `== true`.  Simply check `if boolValue {` instead of `if boolValue == true`.  I removed two instances of that.
- You might want to disable the buttons of cards that have been flipped (set `sender.isEnabled = false`) to keep the player from selecting a flipped card.  Remember to reenable them again when they are flipped back by setting their `isEnabled` properties to `true`.

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot. I only changed the if let button block to directly state self.backFlip(sender: self.previousButton!). I didn't really understand why the if let button block was there? (By the way, button = self.previousButton, without self it didn't work). Now I have it all working and a reset button at the end, but how do I make the reset button backFlip all the buttons in the outlet collection?

Comment: The `if let` was just to avoid having to do a force unwrap.  Defensive coding.  If the buttons are in an outlet collection, you can do something like `for button in collection { if !button.isEnabled { self.backFlip(sender: button); button.isEnabled = true } }`.  That will only work if you've implemented my suggestion to disable flipped cards.  Otherwise, you'll need to determine another way to know if a card is flipped like looking its `tag` up in a list of flipped tags.

Comment: If I do that, I get 'Type UIButton? does not conform to protocol Sequence'? I guess I need to order the collection?

Comment: Then you don't have an @IBOutlet collection.  A collection is an array like this `@IBOutlet var cards: [UIButton]!` and each of the cards is linked to this collection.

Comment: I didn't have it in an Array, just fixed it, the app works now! Thanks again :)